# Add object property value on particular condition with Ramda

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I am new to Ramda and faced a wall trying to do some Object transformations.

I have one Array of Object, have to map it and transform each Object.

**Wanted transformations:**

1. **Rename** each object keys
2. **Add new key** to each Object, based on another key (***value depends on condition***)

**Here it is in code:**

Initial array:

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 1',
    factors: [
      { id: 11, name: '11', },
      { id: 12, name: '12', },
      { id: 13, name: '13', },
      { id: 14, name: '14', },
      { id: 15, name: '15', },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 2',
    factors: [],
  },
];
```

Wanted output array:

```js
const items = [
  {
    key: 1,           // changed property key - already done
    title: 'Name 1',  // changed property key - already done
    factors: [
      { id: 11, name: '11', },
      { id: 12, name: '12', },
      { id: 13, name: '13', },
      { id: 14, name: '14', },
      { id: 15, name: '15', },
    ],
    // add property icon (done)
    // set icon prop based on factors length
    icon: '',        
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: 'Name 2',
    // add property icon (done)
    // set icon prop based on factors length
    icon: 'icon'
  },
];
```

**First goal** in the above list is completed - I can **change property keys** of each Object.
I also can add a new key to each Object. But I **can not set** this new property a value **based on factors** *Array.length*.

**Here is the current code:**

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name 1',
    factors: [
      { id: 11, name: '11', },
      { id: 12, name: '12', },
      { id: 13, name: '13', },
      { id: 14, name: '14', },
      { id: 15, name: '15', },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name 2',
  },
];

const renameKeys = curry((keysMap, obj) =>
  reduce((acc, key) => assoc(keysMap[key] || key, obj[key], acc), {}, keys(obj))
);

const result = map(pipe(
  renameKeys({ id: 'key', name: 'title' }),
  assoc('icon', '---'),  // <= here, set it based on condition - factors.length
), items);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script> const {curry, assoc, map, pipe, reduce, keys} = R </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramda has 2 useful methods to transform objects - [`R.evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve), and [`R.applySpec`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec). Both methods accept an object with keys, and a transform / create (depending on method) function for each key.

In this case you can use `R.applySpec` to generate a new object with the desired key names, and values.

```js
const { map, applySpec, prop, pipe, length, ifElse, always } = R;

const selectIcon = pipe(prop('factors'), length, ifElse(isNaN, always('icon1'), always('icon2')))

const fn = map(applySpec({
  key: prop('id'),
  title: prop('name'),
  factors: prop('factors'),
  icon: selectIcon
}));

const items = [{"id":1,"name":"Name 1","factors":[{"id":11,"name":"11"},{"id":12,"name":"12"},{"id":13,"name":"13"},{"id":14,"name":"14"},{"id":15,"name":"15"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Name 2"}];

const result = fn(items);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The transformer functions can also use `R.applySpec` to change nested values:

```js
const { map, applySpec, prop, pipe, when, length, ifElse, always } = R;

const selectIcon = pipe(prop('factors'), length, ifElse(isNaN, always('icon1'), always('icon2')))

const keysUpdater = {
  key: prop('id'),
  title: prop('name'),
};

const factorsTransformer = pipe(prop('factors'), when(length, map(applySpec(keysUpdater))));

const fn = map(applySpec({
  ...keysUpdater,
  factors: factorsTransformer,
  icon: selectIcon
}));

const items = [{"id":1,"name":"Name 1","factors":[{"id":11,"name":"11"},{"id":12,"name":"12"},{"id":13,"name":"13"},{"id":14,"name":"14"},{"id":15,"name":"15"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Name 2"}];

const result = fn(items);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: In addition, if I want to map over [factors] key and change each object keys: 
key [id] to become [key]
and 
key [name] to become [title]
What is the cleaner way? I tried with mapping over [prop('factors')] but without success.

Comment: key [name] to become an empty string?

Comment: the new key [title] to be with the value of old [name] and the new key [key] to be with the value of [id]. Basically, just change the keys and the values to remain the same.

Comment: I've added another example

Comment: Amazing! Appreciate your assistance Ori! :-)

Comment: Using with Typescript the TS Complier is complaining with the `R.length` method. In JS `0` is false-y value and some number different than 0 is true-thy value. I tried to fix the TS error by adding: `const hasLength = pipe(length, equals(0));` And replacing all length methods with `hasLength`. There is no error BUT it is not changing the properties :). How can i return true/false instead of `0/Number` to make TS compiler happy?

Comment: You can use `is(Array)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In fact I managed to solve it with `const hasLength = pipe(length, equals(0));` and replaced `length` with `hasLength` :). In this case `NaN` should be replaced with `identity (true/false)` and it is working! But I might test it with `is(Array)`.

Comment: I think that it's high time that you accepted this answer. If you have more issues, you should open a new question.